# Laravel 5.2 - validation - One of the fields is required

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

Take a scenario,

```
There are 2 fields available in the form.

1) input type file for manual upload.
2) input type = text to enter youtube video url.
```

is it possible using laravel built-in validations so that validation will be fired if user has left both fields empty!

I have gone through https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation but could not find what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you could do something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'link_upload' => 'required|etc|...',
]);

$validator2 = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file_upload' => 'required|etc|...',
]);

if ($validator->fails() && $validator2->fails()) {
    // return with errors
}
```

Comment: I am following a practice of creating Form Request class for handling validation. Is it possible using that?

Comment: I think, but not sure, you could use 'required_unless' in your rules array. But that only works if you want one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`required-without-all`](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-without-all) validation rule. As given in documentation:

> The field under validation must be present only when the all of the other specified fields are not present.

---

Assuming your fields name are `url` and `file`, your rule would be like below:

```
$rules = [
    'url' => 'required_without_all:file',
    'file' => 'required_without_all:url'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
required_without:foo,bar,...
```

[The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are not present](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In youre update method add this

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'fileName'=>'required',
      'urlName'=>'required'
]);
```

dont forget to set the fillable in your model

```
protected $fillable = ['fileName','urlName'];
```

Hope this helps